# Why can't Kotlin super type parameters be inferred from constructor?

Tags: generics, kotlin, type-inference

In Kotlin if we have a class w/constructor:

```
open class Wrapper<T>(val value: T)
```

We can call the constructor without specifying the type parameter:

```
val wrapped = Wrapper("value")
```

Specifying the type parameter (e.g. `Wrapper<String>("value")`) is redundant, and IntelliJ will tell you so.

However, if the constructor call is an extends clause, the type parameter is mandatory. E.g.

```
class StringWrapper : Wrapper<String>("value") // compiles
class StringWrapper : Wrapper("value") // does not compile
```

Why can't the type parameter be inferred in this seemingly very similar case?

Comment: I've reported this at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43594.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type parameter certainly *could* be inferred in this case, but there is no code in place in the compiler for doing that yet. JetBrains team member Stanislav Erokhin commented on this [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/infer-generic-type-of-a-base-class-based-on-a-provided-superconstructor-parameter-type/2837) in 2017.

> [...] for now compiler force users declare type arguments for parent
>   class explicitly.

Let's experiment a bit. The check in question in the compiler source code is [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/60c4eb68ff4904782317d1ca4e597b3f213a4f80/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/TypeResolver.kt#L764)

```
if (currentArguments.size != currentParameters.size) {
    c.trace.report(
        WRONG_NUMBER_OF_TYPE_ARGUMENTS.on(
            qualifierPart.typeArguments ?: qualifierPart.expression,
            currentParameters.size, classifierDescriptorChain[index]
        )
    )
    return null
}
```

What if we remove that check? Turns out we get rid of

```
error: one type argument expected for class Wrapper<T>
```

but we don't get much further; instead we get

```
error: type arguments should be specified for an outer class 'Wrapper'. Use full class name to specify them
```

Making it work will require much bigger changes...

So, in short, it is theoretically possible, but not yet implemented.